# webview in android not displaying content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, webview, android-webview

for the blog reader app, the app work when i try to view the treehouse blog site inside of an activity as a webview. But when i try the itunes url or other websites, it doesnt show the content inside of my activity, instead it opens chrome. Now i dont know if this is normal or do i have to add some code for that, thanks. below is the code in the activity i am implementing the webview, thanks

```
package com.paveynganpi.applestorefeed;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class AppleFeedWebViewActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_apple_feed_web_view);

    //get the intent from MainListActivity.java
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri appleFeedUri = intent.getData();

    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl(appleFeedUri.toString());

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_apple_feed_web_view, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the WebView has a null WebViewClient it defaults to this behavior (opening link in a browser). To keep navigations inside of your WebView do this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the required permission in Android Manifest.xml file

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

If the permission is provided, then only reason could be the URL

Add a Log statement to see the value of URL

```
Log.w("URL",appleFeedUri.toString());
```